# My date time picker shows date starts from 1990 not the system date

Tags: android

I have a button by clicking it i am loading a datetimepicker
if (view == startDateButton) {

```
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            //dayOfMonth=Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
                            //monthOfYear=Calendar.MONTH;
                            startDateText.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
                            eventModel.setStartDate(dayOfMonth + "."
                                    + monthOfYear + "." + year);
                        }
                    }, Calendar.getInstance().YEAR,
                    Calendar.getInstance().MONTH, Calendar.getInstance().DATE);
            dpd.show();
```

I want the datetime picker to start from current date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching the current date wrong. Your IDE should display a warning.

Here's the proper way:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                //dayOfMonth=Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
                //monthOfYear=Calendar.MONTH;
                setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                        + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
                eventModel.setStartDate(dayOfMonth + "."
                        + monthOfYear + "." + year);
            }
        }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dpd.show();
```